# How to represent a time table from 1-12 with java sysout?

Tags: java

i was wondering how to make a time table from 1-12 with java sysout

here's the time table:

[image]

please advise, thanks.

EDIT: this was a question in an interview to be answered in less than 10 seconds, and i couldn't figure it out in time.

BTW, the empty row is not important.

Comment: Image cannot be seen. Try describing it.

Comment: Use a double for-loop. But this smells like homework.

Comment: Much less effort to do this in Excel.  Unless it's homework, of course.

Comment: You simply wanted to print the above format on the screen ? Am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like homework but I'm giving you a starting point anyway:

```
        for (int y = 1; y <= 12; y++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 12; x++) {
                System.out.print(x * y + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

This gives you the numbers you are looking for. You will have to find a way to align them and print the headers yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 12;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + "\t|");
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            System.out.print((i * j) + "\t|");
            if (j == 12) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can represent it by memorising or there is a trick to the nine times table and the other the trick is if you know your five or other times tamales until where you mnow for example I know until my sixes then you will know what one times six is because it is the one times table and you will know what times six is because it is in the two times table you will know it until six times five because know your going to start your sixes

Comment: It is *extremely difficult* to tell what you are saying here, as you've posted a single block of text with no paragraphs, or even punctuation.